# C# empty term - Why is this allowed? (odd syntax)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I was in a situation wherein I had to regex-parse some C# code for a little task, and was tripped-up by something which I would have assumed was C# syntax error:

```
var moop = new { Moop = "Hello", };
```

This compiles correctly.

My question - What purpose does allowing a trailing comma / empty term serve?

It's valid in arrays, too:

```
var arr = new[]{1,2,3,};
```

Comment: _"What purpose does allowing a trailing comma / empty term serve?"_ - probably to make copy paste new elements easily ;)

Comment: If they take a dedicated line each, then adding another element would cause 1 line diff, instead of 2

Comment: This can be useful where code is autogenerated, eg in WinForms. No edge case for the last element.